# Is there way to use UTF-8 modifer in Symfony2 routing?

Tags: symfony, utf-8

I have following route:

```
library_filter_by_genre:
    path: /library/genre/{genre}/
    defaults: { _controller: noxaeternaMainBundle:Library:filterByGenre }
    requirements:
        genre: "^[-_\w\d]+$"
```

It of course works excellent, but I need UTF-8 support. So I've thought that adding of modifer will allow me to use UTF-8, but with the **u** modifer route doesn't work even with English letters and numbers. I see error:

> No route found for "GET /library/genre/123abc/"

Thanks for reading, I hope you can help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285152/symfony2-routing-requirements-how-to-enable-utf-8-mode