# Symfony2 Routing Requirements: how to enable UTF-8 mode?

Tags: php, regex, symfony, utf-8, url-routing

I want to use the following regex as an requirement for symfony2 routing:

```
/^[ \x{00C0}-\x{01FF}a-zA-Z'\-]+$/u
```

The special thing here is to enable the utf8-mode with the u-modifier at the end. How to pass this /u to requirement-section of a symfony routing.yml?

Our current routing.yml looks like that:

```
search_by_name:
    path:     /search/name/{name}-4/{page}/{limit}
    defaults: { _controller: SearchBundle:SearchByName:index, page: 0, limit: 8 }
    requirements:
        name: "[äüößÄÖÜ´\"`èéa-zA-Z\-]+"
```

Now we want to apply the pattern mentioned above:

```
    requirements:
        name: "[ \x{00C0}-\x{01FF}a-zA-Z'\-]+"  <-- "u" is missing
```

Where to pass the "u"? Just adding the character at the end will result in the following error:

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{...}
>   sequence is too large at offset 61

Comment: Try adding `(*UTF)(*UCP)` at the beginning of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The Symfony Routing component doesn't support fully Unicode ; basically because it doesn't use multibyte-safe string functions internally. Unexpected issues can occurs when using such flags.

Progress in Unicode support in the component is tracked in the following issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5236

Comment: What is a possible best solution for that outside of the current implementation in your opinion - having the regular expressions in the web server route matching or through the implementation of a customer UrlMatcher and having it override the default one?